# Jsf urlrewrite not working

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, url-rewriting, tuckey-urlrewrite-filter

i want to hide my page extension without using pretty faces cuz it's hard to use and I'm confusing about using that , now i'm using tuckey http://tuckey.org/urlrewrite/

i have this link : 
    localhost1:8080/control/login.xhtml

```
so i want it like : localhost1:8080/control/login
```

my code is :

```
<urlrewrite>

<rule>
    <note>
        The rule means that requests to /test/status/ will be redirected to /rewrite-status
        the url will be rewritten.
    </note>
    <from>login.xhtml</from>
    <to type="redirect">control/login</to>
</rule>
```

but it gives me :

```
HTTP Status 404 - /control/login
 for that link : 
 localhost:8080/control/login
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are redirecting to *control/login*, you will also need to define a navigation rule that will map this url to an xhtml page.

Example

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<faces-config
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_0.xsd"
version="2.0">


<navigation-rule>
<from-view-id>*.xhtml</from-view-id>
<navigation-case>
    <from-outcome>control/login</from-outcome>
    <to-view-id>login.xhtml</to-view-id>
</navigation-case>
</navigation-rule>


</faces-config>
```

Comment: there is no new happens , i have changed it in faces config but still same link give me 404